# Error when writing to report file after successful test execution

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, report, nightwatch.js

I've tried to set up HTML reporting in nightwatch by adding handlebars etc but after I do all that when I try to run a test the test runs but I get the following error message and the report is never created:

> Error: An error occurred while trying to save the report file:
> Error: The reporter module must have a public “.write()” method defined.
>     at C:\Users\Beller\automation\node_modules\nightwatch\lib\reporter\global-reporter.js:130:15
>     at async GlobalReporter.writeReportToFile
> (C:\Users\Beller\automation\node_modules\nightwatch\lib\reporter\global-reporter.js:141:24)
>     at async Promise.all (index 1) at async DefaultRunner.reportResults
> (C:\Users\Beller\automation\node_modules\nightwatch\lib\runner\test-runners\default.js:119:7)
>     at async DefaultRunner.run
> (C:\Users\Beller\automation\node_modules\nightwatch\lib\runner\test-runners\default.js:140:7).
>
> Error: The reporter module must have a public “.write()” method
> defined.
>     at async Promise.all (index 1)
>
> at async Promise.all (index 1)

not sure what I need to do here…. any help would be greatly appreciated

Not sure how to fix this.  Has anyone else seen an issue similar?

Answer (score 1):

HI I think I may have solved this now? Try the below which needs to be in your global.js file.

```
    var HtmlReporter = require('nightwatch-html-reporter');
var reporter = new HtmlReporter

module.exports = {
    before: function (done) {
        chromedriver.start();
        done();
    },

    after: function (done) {
        chromedriver.stop();
        done();
    }
};

({
    openBrowser: true,
    reportsDirectory: __dirname + '/reports'
});
module.exports = {
    reporter: reporter.fn
};
```